# Process after cxf out interceptor in camel

Tags: apache-camel, camel-cxf

I have a route that start with cxf endpoint like this:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="CXFTest" address="/javainuse/learn"
                 endpointName="a:SOATestEndpoint" serviceName="a:SOATestEndpointService"
                 serviceClass="com.javainuse.SOATestEndpoint"
                 xmlns:a ="http://javainuse.com">
    <cxf:binding>
        <soap:soapBinding mtomEnabled="false" version="1.2" />
    </cxf:binding>

    <cxf:features>
        <wsa:addressing  xmlns:wsa="http://cxf.apache.org/ws/addressing"/>
    </cxf:features>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor" />
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.DefaultCryptoCoverageChecker" />
        <ref bean="TAXWSS4JInInterceptorBean" />            
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor" />
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.DefaultCryptoCoverageChecker" />            
        <ref bean="TAXWSS4JInInterceptorBean" />            
    </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor" />
        <ref bean="TAXWSS4JOutInterceptorBean" />
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor" />
        <ref bean="TAXWSS4JOutInterceptorBean" />
    </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>


<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="cxf:bean:CXFTest" />
        <to uri="bean:processor"/>
    </camel:route>
</camelContext>
```

and I have several out interceptor that I process in it. now when route is finished, the response cross of the out interceptor but I want send my messages to queue after processing in out intercepotrs. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your Camel route can't because in- and out-interceptors are "wrapped around" your client or server implementation by CXF. It is **by design** that the endpoint implementation (your Camel route) does not need to care about them.

If you want to manipulate the request before the first interceptor or the response after the last interceptor, you have to **implement a CXF interceptor by yourself** that runs as first/last interceptor.

There are [multiple phases for in and out](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html), you can attach your interceptor to, to tell CXF when to execute it.

Comment: thanks burki for your response. I want to send data to activemq by camel after out interceptor but as you mentioned this is not possible by camel and I should send data in a custom interceptor. thanks again.